# Bootstrap modal on React doesn't show the value of argument passed by parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a project with its front end in React. This is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Tree from 'react-d3-tree';
import { useCenteredTree } from "./helpers";
import datas from '../data/dati.json'
import ViewInfo from "./ViewInfo";

const containerStyles = {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    position: "relative"
};

const renderForeignObjectNode = ({
                                     nodeDatum,
                                     toggleNode,
                                     foreignObjectProps,
                                     setNomeSelezionato
                                 }) => (
    <g>
        <circle r={15} fill="#87C462"></circle>
        <foreignObject {...foreignObjectProps} >
            <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", backgroundColor: "#9BB38C", borderRadius: "7px", color: "white"}}>
                <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{nodeDatum.name}</h3>

                <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
                    data-bs-target="#ViewInfo"
                    aria-controls="offcanvasExample"
                    style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#9BB38C", borderColor: "#6C7D62", color: "black" }}
                    onClick={() => setNomeSelezionato(nodeDatum.name)} // Now setSelectedName is accessible
                >
                    Info
                </button>
                {nodeDatum.children && (
                    <button style={{ width: "100%", borderBottomRightRadius: "7px", borderBottomLeftRadius: "7px" ,backgroundColor: "#9BB38C",borderColor: "#6C7D62"}} onClick={toggleNode} >
                        {nodeDatum.__rd3t.collapsed ? "Espandi" : "Comprimi"}
                    </button>
                )}
            </div>
        </foreignObject>


    </g>
);



const containerStylesWithBackground = {
    ...containerStyles,
    background: "#D2D8CF" // Cambia il colore dello sfondo
};

function OrgChart() {
    const [translate, containerRef] = useCenteredTree();
    const nodeSize = { x: 200, y: 200 };
    const foreignObjectProps = { width: nodeSize.x, height: nodeSize.y, x: 20 };
    const [nomeSelezionato, setNomeSelezionato] = useState('');
    return (
        <div style={containerStylesWithBackground} ref={containerRef}>
            <Tree
                data={datas}
                pathFunc={"step"}
                translate={translate}
                nodeSize={nodeSize}
                renderCustomNodeElement={(rd3tProps) =>
                    renderForeignObjectNode({ ...rd3tProps, foreignObjectProps,setNomeSelezionato })
                }
                orientation="vertical"/>
                <ViewInfo selectedName={nomeSelezionato}/>
        </div>


    );
}

export default OrgChart;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import InfoDipendenti from "./InfoDipendenti";
import InfoDipendentiModal from "./InfoDipendentiModal";

function ViewInfo({selectedName}) {
    console.log(selectedName)
    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([
        { name: 'Giuseppe Magliano', role: 'CEO' },
        { name: 'Francesco Magliano', role: 'CoCapo' },
        // TODO get dipendenti by DipartName
    ]);

    const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee] = useState(null);

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const toggleModal = () => {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabIndex="-1" id="ViewInfo" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel" style={{ backgroundColor: "#889460" }}>
                <div className="offcanvas-header">
                    <h5 className="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">
                        Info dipartimento:
                    </h5>
                    <h3>{selectedName}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="offcanvas-body">
                    <div>
                        Qui ci sarà la descrizione
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <br/>
                        <h5>Dipendenti:</h5>
                        {employees.map((employee, index) => (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <br/>
                                <button type="button" onClick={toggleModal} style={{backgroundColor: "#9BB38C", borderColor: "#6C7D62", color: "black", borderRadius:"7px" }}>
                                    {employee.name}
                                    <br/>
                                    {employee.role}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {selectedEmployee && (
                <div className="popup">
                    {/* ... rest of the component ... */}
                </div>
            )}

            {/* Modal */}
            <InfoDipendentiModal showModal={showModal} toggleModal={toggleModal} employees={selectedEmployee} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default ViewInfo;
```

As you can see, in the OrgChart function, the ViewInfo function is called, and the 'nomeSelezionato' variable is passed as a parameter.

In the ViewInfo component, I receive 'selectedName' and print it in an h3 element, but the content doesn't appear. In the modal, only the text 'Info dipartimento:' is displayed. I've tried printing the value of 'selectedName' using a console.log, and it's shown in the console without any issues. When inspecting the HTML code, the h3 element is present, but it appears to be empty.

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6Zl.png)
[console messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq1PW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty state variable to store the selected name; you can set it from useEffect on a modal click; you can use the model state variable as useEffect dependencies; and finally, you can pass your selected state into the model.

Comment: I've created a new variable:
`const [employeeSel, setEmployeeSel] = useState(null);`

and an useEffect:
```useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedName) {
            setEmployeeSel(selectedName);
        }
    }, [selectedName]);```

printed the variable value like this:

`<h3>{employeeSel}</h3>`

but it still doesn't work